# Problem with a custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, web-crawler, lookupfield

I've made a custom content type based on the "Page publishing".

In this content type, I've also made a lookup field that lists all items in a list (nothing special with that list though)

When I use my own user to look at a page made with my custom content type, no problem.

When the site is crawled, the crawler doesn't want to index it giving me the error :
“ Content for this URL is excluded by the server because a no-index attribute.”

So I logged in with the same user as the crawler, and when I try to see the page, I get this error :
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

Still, with that user, I can see the list that is used in the lookup field without any problem...

Any idea?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like it was my lookup field because I removed it from the content type and I still got the error... :(

Comment: I've been able to log with the crawler user. With that user, I got an error (access denied), so that's why it wasn't indexing the page. I still didn't figured out why the cralwer doesn't have access but I've temporarily changed the crawler user for my user.

Comment: By the way I removed all my custom fields from the content type and there was still an error with the "Publishing page"